# Retrieving TITLE of current video with YouTube JS API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have created a YouTube player with the YouTube Javascript API that loads up a playlist I have created.

Because the video is chromeless, it does not display controls or video info.
I was hoping to pull the title of the currently playing video and display it underneath. I can pull information such as current time position, and current video duration with things like ytplayer.getDuration() and ytplayer.getCurrentTime().

Wondering if something like "ytplayer.getTitle()" might exist but be undocumented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the title from the ytplayer object, as that's really just an interface to the player controls. But you could add in a quick call to the video feed (perhaps as a part of the onPlayerReady function, but it could really be anywhere). For example, with jQuery this would only require:

```
$.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[videoid]?v=2&alt=json',function(data) {
       title=data.entry.title.$t;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, for everyone that are still looking for answer of this question there is a javascript function:

```
player.getVideoData().title
```

Comment: Could you provide a reference to this function? I couldn't find how to use `getVideoData()` for other info.

Comment: This seems not to work when using the [iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: Apparently, this function is unsupported, it works sometimes but it stopped working for me so I am looking for another soution

Answer (score 1):

If you use the getVideoData method, you will get access to the title.
See the codesnipped, i tried this and it printed the line below to the console.

```
console.log(player.getVideoData().title);
Necrotic Flesh - Prenatal Decomposed
```